# Stack Exchange websites report bad hostname when using fully-qualified domain names

Tags: feature-request, bug

[stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) loads just fine, but [stackoverflow.com.](http://stackoverflow.com.) (mind the trailing dot) reports *HTTP Error 400: Bad Request - Invalid Hostname*.

I understand that my browser sends `stackoverflow.com.` which is not equal to `stackoverflow.com`, but other major websites just redirect me instead of responding with an error: [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com.), [Facebook](http://facebook.com.), [GitHub](https://github.com./stackexchange), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Domain_Name_System). Note that the latter even preserves the dot in the URL instead of redirecting me.

Comment: *Yawn*, yeah, the real hostname loads just fine, so what's the problem. [stackoverfl0w.com](http://stackoverfl0w.com/) yields `404`. That's just 4 more.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi added details on my opinion: some other major websites load with fully-qualified domain names just fine and I don't see a reason why fully-qualified name is worse than what we're used to. Maybe this should be a "feature request" and not a "bug", though.

Comment: Maybe it is both. I am not sure pandering to users who cannot type a domain name is the right way to go in terms of features here, but I added the tag nonetheless. I'm Voltairian like that.

Comment: Wikipedia very cleverly sends me to an untrusted connection, since the `.` is significant in SSL certificate matching. I'm not impressed by the quality of your examples.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that's very strange: I've tried that in Chrome and Firefox, they do not object and display the page as fully secured ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XI3D9.png)). Maybe it's a bug in both of them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong about that. The trailing dot is a part of hostname, so your browser sends a HTTP request with header `Host: stackoverflow.com.` to `stackoverflow.com` IP address, which is invalid.

Comment: Well, I would expect the site work as usual. Say, Google, GitHub, Facebook handle this just fine with redirection to a "non-dotted" version. Added this opinion to the question.